# Is 'liking' a web page on the actual page different than 'liking' FB post that shares a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-like

If I 'like' a post that is a shared a web page within Facebook, is that in any way connected to the number of likes that are shown on the actual web page in the Facebook share button?

Put otherwise: To acquire likes on an external web page, does one actually need to click the like button on that external page?

Put slightly otherwise: Is there any way within Facebook to add to the number of likes shown on an external web page's facebook like button?

Answer (score 1):

I have often wondered the same thing. Looking at the respective pages for the **[Like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button?locale=th_TH)** and **[Share](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button?locale=th_TH)** buttons, the answer is not 100% clear if the *Likes of a Share* are added to the *Likes of a page* but this question, which is on both pages, seems to imply that they are (in the third point):

> **What makes up the number shown next to my Share button?**
>
> The number shown is the sum of:
>
> - The number of likes of your URL
> - The number of shares of your URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
> - The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about your URL